# Airflow unable to fetch the success status from dataflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow

When submitting a dataflow job from airflow , its unable to fetch the success status of the dataflow job and keeps displaying the below error.

```
{gcp_dataflow_hook.py:77} INFO - Google Cloud DataFlow job not available yet..
```

airflow Dag

```
t2 = DataFlowPythonOperator(
task_id='google_dataflow',
py_file='/Users/abc/sample.py',
gcp_conn_id='connection_id',
dataflow_default_options={
    "project": 'Project_id'
    "runner": "DataflowRunner",
    "staging_location": 'gs://Project_id/staging',
    "temp_location": 'gs://Project_id/staging'
}
)
```

Sample.py

```
def run():
argv = [
        '--project={0}'.format(PROJECT),
        '--staging_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
        '--temp_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
        '--runner=DataflowRunner'
    ]

with beam.Pipeline(argv=argv) as p:
  (p | 'read_bq_table' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
        query = 'Select * from `ds.table` limit 10', 
        use_standard_sql=True))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

have read other answers in the forum, and as suggested i removed the jobnames from sample.py as well as Airflow dag , but still airflow is unable to fetch the success return code.

From airflow log when the job gets submitted to dataflow

```
{gcp_dataflow_hook.py:116} INFO - Running command:  python /Users/abc/sample.py 
--runner=DataflowRunner -- project=project_id --region=region_name - 
labels=airflow-version=v1-10-0 --job_name=google_dataflow-f8a478ae
```

after the dataflow job is completed

```
{gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - INFO:root:Job 2018-10-26_06_07_04- 
 17336980599969256162 is in state JOB_STATE_DONE
{gcp_api_base_hook.py:90} INFO - Getting connection using a JSON key file.
{discovery.py:866} INFO - URL being requested: GET 
https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/project_id/locations/us- 
central1/jobs?alt=json
{gcp_dataflow_hook.py:77} INFO - Google Cloud DataFlow job not available yet..
```

Not sure how to sort this out , can someone help

Dataflow Job Summary from console

```
Job name beamapp-user-1026130638-681570
Job ID 2018-10-26_06_07_04-17336980599969256162
Region us-central1
Job statusSucceeded
SDK version Apache Beam SDK for Python 2.7.0
```

Comment: There seems to be two job_name  beamapp-user-1026130638-681570 & google_dataflow-f8a478ae which might be causing the issue.

Comment: @Ramanandjaiswal yes i see that but unable to have a fixed name , even though i specify the job name , airflow appends its own value as suffix , how to get rid of this ?

Comment: What's airflow version you are using ?

Comment: @Ramanandjaiswal v1.10.0

Comment: Extended Log while fetching the Dataflow status [2018-10-29 14:57:21,264] {discovery.py:866} INFO - URL being requested: GET https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/Project_id/locations/us-central1/jobs?alt=json
[2018-10-29 14:57:23,645] {http.py:119} WARNING - Encountered 403 Forbidden with reason "forbidden"

Comment: Resolved the Issue : Instead of importing directly from contribution take it to your local and import the packages both hook and DataflowPythonoperator , #from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataFlowPythonOperator instead from operators.dataflow_operator import DataFlowPythonOperator (local) aswell for the hook #from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_dataflow_hook import DataFlowHook to from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook(local)

Comment: The last comment "Resolved the issue" should be a valid answer instead of a comment. Thank you for sharing your progress.