# Unable to get the dataflow job state using httpMethod and URL from Airflow

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow, airflow

1. I am Submitting a dataflow job via airflow v1.10.0(Installed in local machine)
2. The job gets submitted and executes successfully, but airflow does not exit based on the job state.

Could someone help in resolving this issue

The code block for the same is available in [Triggering dataflow using airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009855/airflow-unable-to-fetch-the-success-status-from-dataflow)

Below is the log message

```
[2018-10-29 16:47:48,313] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - INFO:root:Job 
2018-10-29_04_17_36-2871901639034996418 is in state JOB_STATE_RUNNING
[2018-10-29 16:47:48,313] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - INFO:root:2018- 
10-29T11:17:42.201Z: JOB_MESSAGE_DEBUG: Tearing down pending resources...
[2018-10-29 16:47:48,313] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:128} WARNING - INFO:root:Job 
2018-10-29_04_17_36-2871901639034996418 is in state JOB_STATE_DONE
[2018-10-29 16:47:48,314] {gcp_api_base_hook.py:90} INFO - Getting connection 
using a JSON key file.
[2018-10-29 16:47:48,319] {discovery.py:267} INFO - URL being requested: GET 
https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/dataflow/v1b3/rest
[2018-10-29 16:47:52,744] {discovery.py:866} INFO - URL being requested: GET 
https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/dataflow-219809/locations/us- 
central1/jobs?alt=json
[2018-10-29 16:47:55,060] {gcp_dataflow_hook.py:77} INFO - Google Cloud 
DataFlow job not available yet..
```

Comment: Resolved the Issue : Instead of importing directly from contribution take it to your local and import the packages both hook and DataflowPythonoperator , **from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataFlowPythonOperator** >> **operators.dataflow_operator import DataFlowPythonOperator** (local) aswell for the hook **from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcp_dataflow_hook import DataFlowHook** >> **from airflow.contrib.hooks.gcs_hook import GoogleCloudStorageHook**(local)

Comment: Please add your comment as an answer and accept it.